# Powershell hashtable does not write to file as expected - receive only "System.Collections" rows

Tags: powershell, hashtable

Can someone please explain ***Why*** my first examples don't work, and why adding in a ForEach-Object solves the problem?  Thanks in advance!

---

I parsed the return from a command into a hashtable (sample at end of post) and want to log the information to a file as part of my processing.  I know that `$ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name` will return the full hash to screen, sorted.  However, once I try sending things to file, it breaks.

```
$ht | Add-Content log.txt
```

only logs a single row of `System.Collections.Hashtable`.  So, I've also tried

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | Add-Content log.txt
```

and end up with rows of

```
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

So then I tried to loop through and handle each individually with

```
foreach ($key in $ht.keys) {
Add-Content log.txt "$key : $ht.$key" }
```

and end up with

```
Server address : System.Collections.Hashtable.Server address
Client address : System.Collections.Hashtable.Client address
User name : System.Collections.Hashtable.User name
```

*Solved with*:

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name |
ForEach-Object {"{0} : {1}" -f $_.Name,$_.Value} |
Add-Content log.txt
```

---

For reference, the hashtable sample:

```
$ht = @{
    "Server address" = "server.net";
    "Client address" = "10.20.121.153";
    "User name" = "myuser"
}
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering the **why** part, you obviously have a solution :)

In your first example

```
$ht | Add-Content log.txt
```

PowerShell takes `$ht` and tries to somehow convert it to a string so that it can be stored via `Add-Content`. Because there is no conversion defined for the hashtable, only the type name is returned from the conversion. Same as for example `new-Object Random|Add-Content d:\log.txt`. Again, only type name is written.

Next

```
$ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | Add-Content log.txt
```

is similar. `GetEnumerator` returns object that is used for iteration; objects of type `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry` are returned. Again, there is no conversion to string, so type names are returned.

Personally, I think PowerShell should be smart enough and help here. The question is "how?". Designers probably didn't want to hardcode the output. It might be `"{key}: {value}"` or `"{key} = {value}"`, or `"{key}/{value}"`, or ... The format is not clear, so they left it for us to decide and format as you did it with the `foreach` statement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - I knew it had to be something with the conversion to strings, I just was not grasping the mechanisms involved.  The combination of your elucidation and the more specific examples from everyone have helped immensely!

Answer (score 11):

I agree with mjolinor... just not enough points to vote up... plus i'll add that you dont need the GetEnumerator

```
$ht | out-string | add-content log.txt
```

will do it.

Answer (score 6):

Your first example does not work, or better, partially works, because you are trying to get a property value within the string. Normally, inside strings, the parser is able to resolve only direct variables (like `$key`). To resolve more complex variable you need parenthesis.

For the loop, this should work:

```
foreach ($key in $ht.keys) {
Add-Content log.txt "$key : $($ht.$key)" }
```

or even better

```
$ht.keys | %{ Add-Content log.txt "$_ : $($ht.$_)" }
```

Comment: Thanks for the one-liner solution - the brevity is nice.  Though I think after reading the others, I'm leaning towards combining your abbreviations with my sort and slightly more explicit format for readability.

Answer (score 6):

As you can see in Microsoft documentation a hash table is simply a collection of name-value pairs.

So `$ht` is really `System.Collections.Hashtable` composed of `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`.

A good way to use it is

```
foreach ($i in $ht.keys)
{
  add-content log.txt ("{0} {1}" -f $i, $ht[$i])
}
```

Comment: Ah...  so my original loop was so close.  So forcing the formatting converts to strings that add-content handles gracefully.  Gotcha.

Answer (score 3):

How about:

```
 $ht.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Name | out-string | Add-Content log.txt
```

Comment: Interesting - this also has the benefit of spitting out the headers as well - it'll come in handy when I want those in the future - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can write a "raw" dump of a hash table to an ASCII file using Out-File:

```
$data = @{
  Name = "Something"
  Type = "123"
}
$data | Out-File "myfile.txt" -Encoding ascii
```

Comment: This does not work for any significantly complex hash tables.