# How to get Powershell ACL information in a hash to print nicely to a file

Tags: powershell, hash, hashtable

I am developing a script to compare access permissions between two different file locations. My question is similar to [this question about System.Collections](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5954503/powershell-hashtable-does-not-write-to-file-as-expected-receive-only-system-c?rq=1) in that I am recording information to a hash table, but it isn't printing to a file in a readable way.

Here is my code

```
Get-ChildItem -path $location1 -recurse | ForEach{$original_file_permissions[$_.name] = (Get-ACL $_.fullname).Access; Write-Host Parsing $_.fullname}
$original_file_permissions.getenumerator() | Format-Table | Out-File "U:\file_folder\sub_folder\original_file_permissions.txt
```

My code parses a file location, using the Get-ACL method to capture the Access details of that file or folder, storing it as the value in the hash table where the key is the file or folder title. However, the file that the hash prints to doesn't print the exact details, it instead prints, I believe, a System class? I'm not exactly sure.

Here is what the file looks like

```
sys.a90                        {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}                                                                                                                                                
pickering-app_beta_02.hex      {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}                                                                                                                                                
release_notes.txt              {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}                                                                                                                                                
126037AA                       {System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule, System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule}
```

However when I run the same command in the PowerShell terminal and access a key, I get the ACL details that I'm looking for.

```
PS C:\file_folder\sub_folder> $hash["126037AA"]


FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : user123
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None

FileSystemRights  : FullControl
AccessControlType : Allow
IdentityReference : admin
IsInherited       : True
InheritanceFlags  : ContainerInherit, ObjectInherit
PropagationFlags  : None                          
...
```

Why exactly is this happening? And how can I make it so that the ACL details in the hash are what prints to the file?

Comment: You need to be accessing the member you're trying to print otherwise it's printing the object type to the file.

Comment: Okay so it's printing the object type. Does .GetEnumerator() not access each member of the hash table?

Comment: No, it's basically the same as typing `$Hash` except you can't access the members by `.GetEnumerator().Key`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are trying to output an object to a flatfile(txt file) so the acl object is being written as a type. In other words out-file does not know how to write the acl object so we need to convert the object to a string and then output file.

```
$original_file_permissions.getenumerator() | 
  Foreach-Object { 
   '{0}{1}' -f $_.key, ($_.Value | out-string)   
  } | out-file c:\temp\acl.txt
```

or

```
$original_file_permissions.getenumerator() | 
  Foreach-Object { 
    $_.Value | Add-Member Noteproperty Name $_.key -PassThru -Force      
  } | Format-Table | Out-File c:\temp\acl.txt
```

you could write the acl info as a csv but you would need to put in some more work.

Also notice i removed the `format-table` - this is because format-table changes the object type and is generally used only to display stuff in the console.

Comment: Thank you very much. The other answer wasn't working for me because I was keeping the Format-Table in the statement, thinking it was necessary. Weird that it's generally only used in the console, I've seen it in lots of other answers.

Comment: welcome...it seems that out-file understands the objects coming out of format-table which means we can improve the output :)...see the edit...but yeah format-table outputs `format` objects which dont play nice with other cmdlets...but out-file seems to work

Answer (score 0):

`System.Security.AccessControl.DirectorySecurity` has a `ScriptProperty` called `Accesstostring`. You could use that but you still have the issue that you have one file object, but one or more access entries. That does not fit to your text output.

I think you will have to go down to each access rule and add the file name or what ever information you need there.

```
$items = Get-ChildItem
foreach ($item in $items) {
    $acl = Get-Acl -Path $item.FullName  # Before edit this was $items.FullName
    foreach ($access in $acl.Access) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Name              = $item.Name
            FullName          = $item.FullName
            FileSystemRights  = $access.FileSystemRights
            AccessControlType = $access.AccessControlType
            IdentityReference = $access.IdentityReference            
        }
    }
}
```

That object you can easily output in a text file as csv or printed format-table. Each access rule will be one line.